# How to split a poem in python

Tags: python, split

I am trying to split a text which contains slashes that split words into syllables as well.
For example

```
text = "Hi! I do/n'/t know how ma/ny sy/lla/bu/s a/re  the/re i/n thi/s te/x/te, who kno/w."
result = re.split('; |/| |. |, ', text)
```

The problem is that I don't get the correct number of syllables, nor the last letter before any space!

Any help please!

Comment: what output do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a regular expression, `"."` matches any character, so `". "` matches `"{any character}{space}"`.

To match a literal period, you need to use `"\."` or put it in a character set (`[.]`).

Try

```
syllables = re.compile("[.,:;!?]? |/").split
text = "Hi! I do/n'/t know how ma/ny sy/lla/bu/s a/re  the/re i/n thi/s te/x/te, who kno/w."

print(syllables(text))
```

which gives

```
['Hi', 'I', 'do', "n'", 't', 'know', 'how', 'ma', 'ny', 'sy', 'lla', 'bu', 's', 'a', 're', '', 'the', 're', 'i', 'n', 'thi', 's', 'te', 'x', 'te', 'who', 'kno', 'w.']
```

Comment: Thank you very much !! I just added \n to handle the case where there an end of line or in other way multiple lines. However there is still a problem where there is more than one space !! how can I add it to syllabus = re.split('[.,:;!?]? |/|\n', text)

Comment: Try `"[.,:;!?]? +|/"` instead (added `+`, meaning "one or more spaces")

Comment: Thank it works ! I just wanted to know what to add to handle the case when there is a space or more before an end of line '\n'

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can use [str.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm) and a normal split:

```
from string import maketrans
text = "Hi! I do/n'/t know how ma/ny sy/lla/bu/s a/re  the/re i/n thi/s te/x/te, who kno/w."
tr = maketrans("/,.'","    ")
print(text.translate(tr)).split()

['Hi!', 'I', 'do', 'n', 't', 'know', 'how', 'ma', 'ny', 'sy', 'lla', 'bu', 's', 'a', 're', 'the', 're', 'i', 'n', 'thi', 's', 'te', 'x', 'te', 'who', 'kno', 'w']
```

If you want to keep the `'` like in `do/n'/t`:

```
tr = maketrans("/,.","   ")
print(text.translate(tr)).split()

['Hi!', 'I', 'do', "n'", 't', 'know', 'how', 'ma', 'ny', 'sy', 'lla', 'bu', 's', 'a', 're', 'the', 're', 'i', 'n', 'thi', 's', 'te', 'x', 'te', 'who', 'kno', 'w']
```

If you want to keep the period remove it from the maketrans also

Comment: @HughBothwell, I added both, It is just a matter of including a `'` in maketrans or not

Comment: I agree; I was just pointing it out, and it looks like you were solving it already.

Comment: @HughBothwell, I actually had it that way originally but starting second guessing, not totally clear from the OP's question exactly what it should be.